# Filter disposable email addresses without exposing the address to a third party

Tags: email-validation

In order to prevent users from signing up with my site using a disposable email address, I want to check the email address during registration. I found many web services that offer to validate an email address against its internal disposable email domain list. I've also found questions/answers here in Stack Overflow what explicitly recommend this method.

I think using this method is a very bad idea. Because of privacy concerns (or even privacy policies), you shouldn't ever expose the users email address (or even only its domain part) to a third party.

I've found some public lists, but neither seem to be updated:

- https://gist.github.com/michenriksen/8710649
- https://gist.github.com/adamloving/4401361
- http://www.digitalfaq.com/forum/web-tech/5050-throwaway-email-block.html

Does anyone know a publicly available list, which is updated regularly?

Comment: What is your question? You're talking about privacy, but all you seem to be asking for is a maintained list of disposable email domains, which is off-topic for SO.

Comment: My question is: "Do anyone know a publicly available list, which is updated regularly?". I think I reasoned why it is a development question. If you think there is a better place to expose this question (and hopefully the coming answers) to the developer community, please feel free to share. Also as you wrote "talking about privacy". That is why I found some _incorrect_ ideas here in stackoverflow. So I think "talking about privacy" related to this question is for benefit for all web developers who will search for a solution _here_ in stackoverflow.

Comment: Asking for off-site resources if off-topic for SO. Also I asked what you meant, because from your question it isn't that clear that you simply don't want to send your user's email addresses to a third-party service to check them.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Sorry I thought it was clear "nobody wants to send their user's email address to a 3rd party".

Comment: Yes, you'd have to download a set of throwaway mail domains to do this, rather than sending the user's address to a third party. Whether it is a good or a bad idea to reject throwaway email addresses depends on the service you are building though - if you value your users' privacy, maybe you should allow them?

Comment: @halfer: You are right about it is not always effective business strategy to ban disposable emails. However in many cases it is part of the security, and I am seeking for this. It seems this issue currently has no good solution, but in case this question will not be deleted as off topic, sooner or later it will have answer, for all's benefit who are actually asking this question

Comment: Well, I think banning disposable emails may not be an effective _privacy_ strategy. Can you explain in more detail how this helps your site's security? I appreciate there is generally a security/privacy balance, but more detail may help here. As I say, the correct answer in your case _may_ be just to allow throwaway emails, but without more detail, it is not possible for us to take a view.

Comment: @halfer: I did not say that banning disposable emails is about _privacy_. I said it is about _security_. I've talked about privacy in relation to giving out the emails to a 3rd party.

Comment: No, you did not. But I did, because that is my opinion. Allowing disposable email addresses has a lot to do with the maintenance of privacy.

Answer (score 1):

See www.block-disposable-email.com for a source of disposable email domains. While the api access is the best way to get most recent responses a download for offline use is available for enterprise users (http://www.block-disposable-email.com/cms/help-and-usage/).

Public/free lists are not very reliable in my experience.

Full disclosure: I am a co-founder of this service that detects more than 6.500 dea domains (without false positives).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this free JavaScript library: https://github.com/AppBeat-io/JavaScript

Usage example:

```
AppBeat.Email.isDisposable('something@sharklasers.com'); //returns true
AppBeat.Email.isDisposable('something@mailinator.com'); //returns true
AppBeat.Email.isDisposable('   something@mailinator.com   '); //returns true
AppBeat.Email.isDisposable('@mailinator.com'); //returns true
AppBeat.Email.isDisposable('mailinator.com'); //returns true
AppBeat.Email.isDisposable('unknown-domain.some-domain'); //returns false
AppBeat.Email.isDisposable('something@unknown-domain.some-domain'); //returns false
AppBeat.Email.isDisposable('something@gmail.com'); //returns false (whitelisted)
AppBeat.Email.isDisposable('something@outlook.com'); //returns false (whitelisted)
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you will need to use some sort of anti-fraud service or api validator. I personally use ipqs since its free for me (I use under 5,000 monthly lookups)

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about sharing the addresses with a third party I would recommend using my assets repository:
https://assetsapi.com/lukas/disposable-emails/v1.0.0/readme.md

This asset is constantly updated with the latest disposable email domains and suppliers. Implementation is very easy and http://assetsapi.com allows you to download the entire dataset and do matching on your end.